# The method 'contains' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

Hey guys this is my code: Im trying to display available time slots for my booking app.

```
   Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getTimeSlotOfCourt(
          courtModel,
          DateFormat('dd_MM_yyyy').format(context.read(selectedDate).state),
        ),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            var listTimeSlot = snapshot.data as List<int>;
            return GridView.builder(
                itemCount: TIME_SLOT.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: listTimeSlot.contains(index)
                          ? null
                          : () {
                              context.read(selectedTime).state =
                                  TIME_SLOT.elementAt(index);
                              context.read(selectedTimeSlot).state = index;
                            },
                      child: Card(
                        color: listTimeSlot.contains(index)
                            ? Colors.white10
                            : context.read(selectedTime).state ==
                                    TIME_SLOT.elementAt(index)
                                ? Colors.white54
                                : Colors.white,
                        child: GridTile(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text('${TIME_SLOT.elementAt(index)}'),
                                Text(listTimeSlot.contains(index)
                                    ? 'Full'
                                    : 'Available')
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          header: context.read(selectedTime).state ==
                                  TIME_SLOT.elementAt(index)
                              ? Icon(Icons.check)
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
          }
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

}

I'm getting this error which says the method 'contains' was called on null.

```
Future<List<int>> getTimeSlotOfCourt(CourtModel courtModel, String date) async {
List<int> result = new List<int>.empty(growable: true);
  // var ref = CourtModel().refer;
  // var bookingRef = ref.collection(date);
  var bookingRef = CourtModel().reference.collection(date);
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await bookingRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    result.add(int.parse(element.id));
  });
  return result;
}
```

This is the function that I have used.

Please help me understand why I'm getting this error which says The method 'contains' was called on null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot does not always contain data. The Future builder builds once before the future is completed. Null check the snapshot.data and return a spinner or something to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

The future builder only brings data when the future is completed and the snapshot may not contain data all the time. And you are only checking for the waiting state, a better solution would be to check whether the snapshot has data or not.

Something like this would be the preferred solution.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _getTimeSlotOfCourt(),
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         } else {
                 // place you code here  
         }
     }
)
```